# How to train an adaboost classifier?

Tags: opencv, classification, haar-classifier, adaboost

I intend to differentiate between different object by using the `Haar` like base adaboost classifier; I know it only says if it is the object or it is not, so i would have to train one for each kind of object, right? 
However, I am not able to find a tutorial where I am taught how to do this, could you help me?

I also posted it here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/65530/how-to-train-an-adaboost-classifier/

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html

Comment: ok, i know how to do it more of less know, but i have some doubts, I have the training images in .ppm extension, can I make the training with that format? I also have the information about the dataset like this: Filename;Width;Height;Roi.X1;Roi.Y1;Roi.X2;Roi.Y2;ClassId
00000_00000.ppm;56;57;6;5;51;52;1
00000_00001.ppm;55;57;5;6;50;52;1
00000_00002.ppm;56;56;5;6;51;51;1
00000_00003.ppm;58;58;6;6;53;52;1
00000_00004.ppm;59;59;6;6;54;53;1
00000_00005.ppm;57;59;5;6;52;54;1
00000_00006.ppm;57;59;5;5;52;54;1
 May I use that or do I have to obtain new images an description files?

Comment: ppm format is ok. I think you can create annotations files in the specific format.